# In Ubuntu 12.04 my mouse moves automatically, how can i stop it?

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad

As I said in the question's topic, recently my laptop's `touchpad` mouse moves the pointer automatically, I also have installed Windows, but in there i don't have this problem!

how can i fix this?

---

PS: As i am writing this question the mouse is moving :LOL:

Answer (score 0):

See if installing [SynapticsTouchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) will solve this problem.